# For which ordinals do we have $V_\alpha = L_\alpha$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinal-numbers, constructibility

Some elements of $L$ become constructible only in levels higher than its rank level. So I ask:

Let $V$ be such that $V = L$.
For which ordinals $\alpha$ do we have $V_\alpha = L_\alpha$?

Indeed, we have this for $\omega$ and if $\alpha$ is the class of all ordinals. But do we have this for other types of ordinals? Can we, for instance, have $V_\alpha = L_\alpha$ for a singular cardinal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes; in fact the first $\alpha>\omega$ with $V_\alpha=L_\alpha$ has cofinality $\omega$. To obtain this $\alpha$, define $f:Ord\to Ord$ by $f(\xi)=$ the smallest $\eta$ such that $V_\xi\subseteq L_\eta$. Such an $\eta$ exists because of the assumption that $V=L$. Write $f^n$ for the $n$-fold iterate of $f$. Then $\sup_{n\in\omega}f^n(\omega+1)$ is the desired $\alpha$.

More generally, the ordinals you asked about are exactly the fixed points of $f$. Since $f$ is a normal function (increasing and continuous), its fixed points constitute a closed unbounded class of ordinals.

Comment: More explicitly, $V_\alpha = L_\alpha$ if and only if $\alpha \leq \omega$ or $\alpha$ is an $\aleph$-fixed point, i.e., $\aleph_\alpha = \alpha$.
To see this, assume $V_\alpha = L_\alpha$.
Obviously $\alpha\leq \aleph_\alpha$ (for all ordinals $\alpha$).
On the other hand, $|L_\alpha| = \omega\cdot |\alpha|$ (by induction) while $|V_\alpha| = \aleph_\alpha$ (by GCH and induction) so if $V_\alpha = L_\alpha$, then $\aleph_\alpha = \omega\cdot |\alpha|$, which implies $\alpha \leq \omega$ or $\aleph_\alpha = \alpha$.

Comment: I guess I should also say that if $\aleph_\alpha = \alpha$, then $V_\alpha\subseteq L_\alpha$ since $L_\alpha$ is closed under powersets by the condensation lemma.